# EE reading path variables as subfolders/subpages and giving 404 error. What am I missing?

Tags: segments, path

I've got a page: /events/ that I'd like to pass year and month into: /events/2014/07/ ...and access them ({segment_1}, etc) in the template being used for that page.

But when I go to the url http://host.com/events/2014/07, I get a 404 error because it's apparently looking for a subpage named '2014' with a subpage named '07'.

Regarding posting the code:
Why? This doesn't seem to be a code-related issue because I can't even get EE to execute the code in question. The 'events' page is just my standard page template (master/standard). All the pages, for now, use one template. So, /events is using the 'master/standard' template. In it I include 'widgets/calendar' but I want to pass in {segment_2} and {segment_3}. EE won't let me because it doesn't go to the events page. It tries to find a page named "07" under a page named "2014" under the events page. None of this is being handled in the code yet, so I'm not sure what good it would serve to post a bunch of irrelevent EE code.

How do I tell EE to just stop at the events page and use the rest of the url as segments?I know I'm missing some basic EE logic but I'm stumped.

Comment: Please post the code from your "events/index" template please.

Comment: Also please post what version of EE you're running, and what add-ons you're running. (I've tried to get a year-display with EE, like you're trying to do, and I had to install Low Yearly Archives plugin. Then...it worked.)

Comment: How is the `/events` using the `master/standard` template? Routes?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're getting a 404 because the `exp:channel:entries` tag is trying get all entries of the year 2014 and month 07. If you need to use years, months and days as segments, you gonna need to set `dynamic` parameter to `no`.

Take a look at the [URL Schematic](http://www.jamessmith.co.uk/articles/expressionengine_url_schematic)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the full version of expressionengine, you can use [routing](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/template_routes.html) to change how your template handles segments. Otherwise, I believe you would need to [turn strict url's off](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/global_template_preferences.html) in the admin.